# Filter for non-repeated values based on Unique ID

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, group-by, subset

I've the following table

| S/N | Unique ID | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | YES |
| 2 | 111 | YES |
| 3 | 111 | NO |
| 4 | 111 | YES |
| 5 | 222 | YES |
| 6 | 222 | YES |
| 7 | 222 | YES |
| 8 | 222 | YES |
| 9 | 333 | NO |
| 10 | 333 | NO |
| 11 | 333 | YES |
| 12 | 333 | YES |

How do I derive the following table based on the following conditions:
For each unique ID, if YES repeats, keep the first YES. If NO Appears, keep the following YES. I tried using mutate and it's giving me all sort of errors.

| S/N | Unique ID | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | YES |
| 4 | 111 | YES |
| 5 | 222 | YES |
| 11 | 333 | YES |

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a for loop?

Comment: While we can provide code to resolve the immediate issue, you may benefit from learning why your previous attempt failed. For that, please provide the literal error text and code used to produce it. If my answer does not resolve your need, please [edit] your question and add what I've suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### base R

```r
ind <- ave(dat$Code == "YES", dat$`Unique ID`,
           FUN = function(z) z & c(TRUE, !z[-length(z)]))
dat[ind,]
#    S/N Unique ID Code
# 1    1       111  YES
# 4    4       111  YES
# 5    5       222  YES
# 11  11       333  YES
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(`Unique ID`) %>%
  filter(Code == "YES" & lag(Code == "NO", default = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   `S/N` `Unique ID` Code 
#   <int>       <int> <chr>
# 1     1         111 YES  
# 2     4         111 YES  
# 3     5         222 YES  
# 4    11         333 YES
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[, .SD[Code == "YES" & shift(Code == "NO", fill = TRUE),], by = `Unique ID`]
#    Unique ID   S/N   Code
#        <int> <int> <char>
# 1:       111     1    YES
# 2:       111     4    YES
# 3:       222     5    YES
# 4:       333    11    YES
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list("S/N" = 1:12, "Unique ID" = c(111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 333L, 333L, 333L, 333L), Code = c("YES", "YES", "NO", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "YES", "NO", "NO", "YES", "YES")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```